# Excel Viewer for Visual Studio Code not displaying decimal point in string if it follows numerical digits

Tags: python, csv, visual-studio-code

I've included in this example a mix of strings, integers, and floats. This behaviour is unsuprising for integers and floats, however, I would like to ensure that the decimal at the end of strings is always displayed.

Is there a way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a.', '1.'], 'col2': ['1.0.', 1], 'col3': ['11.', 1.]})
display(df)
df.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8')
>>>
    col1    col2    col3
0   a.      1.0.    11.
1   1.      1       1.0
```

`df` rendered with Excel Viewer v4.2.57 in Virtual Studio Code v1.77.3 (Universal)

[image]

Comment: Maybe try setting `pandas.set_option("display.precision", 2)`

Comment: a string with characters `0-9` is NOT a number, it is a sequence of characters. where would you expect a decimal point? An integer does not have a decimal point, a float has, so convert all your numbers in the DF to float by multiplying them with `1.0` (the number not the string)

Comment: @rioV8 Whilst that would solve the issue, I would rather not change the dtype to solve this. Is there perhaps a way to do this on the Excel Viewer side, rather than changing the df to suit the way Excel Viewer handles the resulting csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search `csv-preview.formatValues` in your settings and change it to never.

[image]

[image]